# Trying to add post

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I was trying to add post for a college project but somehow it reloads the page and resets the page. It does not show the post. I tried to submit the form through the add post but it doesn't work.

I'm fairly new to angular so i don't know what to do. Please help me

this is my post.component.html

```html
<h3>Add Post</h3>
<form (formGroup)="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input
    formControlName="title"
    id="title"
    type="text"
    (ngModel)="posts.title"
    class="form-control"
    required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="body">Body</label>
  <input
    formControlName="body"
    id="body"
    type="text"
    (ngModel)="posts.body"
    class="form-control"
    required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button
  class="btn btn-primary"
  type="submit">Add Posts</button>
</div>
</form>
```

this is my post.component.ts for reference

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from './post.model';
import { PostService } from './post.service';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms'
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  id: number;
  form: FormGroup;
  posts: Post;
  post: Post[] = [];

  constructor(
    public postService: PostService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postService.getAll().subscribe((data: Post[])=>{
      this.post = data;
      console.log(this.post);
    })
  }

  submit(){
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.postService.update(this.id, this.form.value).subscribe(res => {
         console.log('Post updated successfully!');
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use reactive form and template driven from same time.
Which means if you are using formControlName don't use ngModel or vice versa.

```
<h3>Add Post</h3>
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input
    id="title"
    type="text"
    name="title"
    [(ngModel)]="posts.title"
    class="form-control"
    required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="body">Body</label>
  <input
    id="body"
    type="text"
    name="body"
    [(ngModel)]="posts.body"
    class="form-control"
    required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button
  class="btn btn-primary"
  type="button" (click)="submit()">Add Posts</button>
</div>
</form>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {

  id: number;
  form: FormGroup;
  posts = { title: '', body: ''};
  post = [];

  constructor(
    public postService: PostService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.postService.getAll().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.post = data;
      console.log(this.post);
    })
  }

  submit(){
    console.log(this.posts);
   this.postService.update(this.id, this.posts).subscribe(res => {
         console.log('Post updated successfully!');
   })
  }
}
```

Please follow the changes made in below link. Here I have used template driven form.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nnphce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html